# Spring Java Mail Configuration

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I'm beeing trying to send mails with spring java mail but i'm not really sure what is going wrong. I made a success using gmail but i want to send mails with my domain.

This is what i try:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="smtp.myhost.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="port123"/>
    <property name="username" value="username123"/>
    <property name="password" value="password123"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.myhost.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

port123, username123, password123 and myhost.com are my credentials from my smtp mail.

I was using almost the same configuration for gmail and it works (There is a lot of gmail examples) but I'm getting troubles using other mail server. I'm starting with java/spring and i have no idea where to find an example of this, I was looking over Internet for a while but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE 1:**
Debug from Java Mail:

```
Información:   DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.4
Información:   DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
Información:   DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
Información:   DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
Información:   DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle],     smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
Información:   DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
Información:   DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
Información:   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
Información:   DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.myhost.com", port "port123", isSSL false
```

And then it stops. It can't connect to Godaddy Server with host `smtp.myhost.com` and port `port123`
Well my server is GoDaddy and i was reading on Internet that you can't let other server to send email. Is this true?

If you have an example to successfully send mails connecting Spring Java mail with Godaddy Server it will help me a lot!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you getting any errors? if so please post stack trace..

Comment: can you post the mail debug logs?

Comment: you can't send a email without smtp server

Comment: Yes, please post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  You might need to set the property `mail.debug` to true.

Comment: I just update with the debug information, it was Godaddy Server